# How To Implement Rich Text in CocosSharp?

Tags: richtext, cclabelttf, cocossharp

Is there a good way to implement Rich Text using the existing CCLabel class or another class? I'ma ttempting to render something like the image below

[image: Image of rich text desired output]

I wasn't able to find any information in the guides on rich text, the wiki entry on CCLabel doesn't mention anything about it, and the documentation doesn't seem to indicate support of rich text. I also didn't find anything searching on these forums for "rich text".

My main problem with concatenating multiple CCLabels together is it makes the word wrapping a challenge. I'm sure if that's the only way to implement this in CocosSharp I can figure it out, but it'd be much nicer to use any built-in support for rich text if it exists.

I know cocos2d-x has support for rich text through their UIRichText class. Does anything like that exist in CocosSharp? Is there a different term I should be searching for, or is there support somewhere in there that I just missed?